# Jupyterhub - Unable to change the start directory

Tags: python-3.x, unix, jupyterhub

I launch jupyterhub as root user and it launches Jupyter Notebook for whitelisted users, landing them to the folder path --> (ip):(port)/(user)/(userid)/tree.  But I want the users taken to the folder path --> 
(ip):(port)/apps/ instead.  For this, I had made the below change in the jupyterhub_config.py file.

```
c.JupyterHub.default_url = '/apps/'
c.Spawner.notebook_dir = '/apps/'
```

But this change lands the users to :/hub/apps/ and shows "404 : Not Found".  When I change the above by commenting out c.Spawner.notebook_dir,it lands the users to :/hub/apps/ and shows "404 : Not Found". Please advise where am I going wrong here...

Answer (score 0):

Commenting out c.JupyterHub.default_url while keeping c.Spawner.notebook_dir worked. Though I don't really understand why it worked, marking this Qn closed, as it worked.